# Set timeout() method is not working when defining an index after the function name in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with executing a set timeout on a function in HTML
I will show you 2 examples one that works the other simply ignore the set timeout method

Working example :
A: onclick="setTimeout(hideBtn, 1000)"
in this example the hidenBtn does not have and index() attached to it and the 1sec delay simply works.

Problematic example :
B: onclick="setTimeout(hideBtn(0), 1000)"
in this example once I define and array index after the function the set time get ignored and the function executes right on click.

do you see any problem with the syntax ?

I will link the whole function from the JS file because I tried to set the set Time out from there but and error occur saying the whole function is not defined ?
since I need the index to be defined I cannot go with working example.
thanks for help.

```js
let g = document.querySelectorAll(".populating-btns");

function hideBtn(index) {
    for (let i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
        g[index].style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="removeA" class="populating-btns">
        <div class="add-btn-extend" onclick="setTimeout(hideBtn(0), 1000)">
            <span>Hide1</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="removeB" class="populating-btns">
        <div class="add-btn-extend" onclick="setTimeout(hideBtn(1), 1000)">
            <span>Hide2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout` needs a **function object** as its first parameter.

What happens now is this:

- The function call `hideBtn(0)` is executed.
- When it ends, it returns `undefined`.
- That `undefined` then gets passed into the `setTimeout(....)` function.

The fix is to create a small new anonymous function using [lambda or arrow notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and pass that anonymous function into `setTimeout`:

```
<div class="add-btn-extend" onclick="setTimeout(() => hideBtn(0), 1000); fadeClick(0);">
    <span>Previous history</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Peter B thanks for the effort to solve the problem it worked have a nice one.

Answer (score 0):

in the first case, from the examples, you pass a function, and in the second - the result of the function

```
<div id="removeA" class="populating-btns">
        <div class="add-btn-extend" onclick="setTimeout(()=>hideBtn(0), 1000); fadeClick(0);">
            <span>Previous history</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

OR

```
<div id="removeA" class="populating-btns">
        <div class="add-btn-extend" onclick="setTimeout(hideBtn, 1000, 0); fadeClick(0);">
            <span>Previous history</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run the for loop outside of the setTimeout, and pass the index to the set timeout. Like this:

```
const g = document.querySelectorAll(".populating-btns");
const btn = document.querySelector('.add-btn-extend');


function hideBtn(index) {
   setTimeout(function(){
      g[index].style.display = "none"; 
   }, 1000)
}


 function setTimeoutOnClick() {
     for (let i = 0; i < g.length; i++) {
         hideBtn(i);
     }
 }
 
 btn.addEventListener('click', setTimeoutOnClick);
```